# Index View Error wrong amount of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm getting an argument error and I am not to sure why. I am still fairly new to using Rails and programming overall. I am currently working on my index page and am just trying to get the description displayed. Below is the view and controller. I am not sure why `t.description` is being expected to have more than one argument. Is this because of strong params?

View:

```
<h1> All Tea Blends </h1>

<% @teas.each do |t| %>
  <h2><%= link_to t.flavor, tea_path(t.id)%> - <%= t.brand.name %></h2>
  <% link_to "Write a review", new_tea_review_path%>
<% end %>

<div>
    <p><%= t.description %></p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class TeasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @teas = Tea.order_by_rating.includes(:brand)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you were referring to the rails error picture I removed it it said I dont have the ability to post embed images yet. But I've further defined my issue in lieu of it.

Comment: I have edited your post to narrow it down to a [mre]. Please take a moment to read that article to understand why. Since the error you receive comes from the index method of your controller that's the only relevant part of that controller.

Comment: Thank you for this I am also reading over the example to follow the paradigm going forward as it is much easier to convey my issue based on that example.

Answer (score 1):

`t.description` is outside of the loop. Not sure why you'd get wrong number of arguments (t is also used for translations, though). Just move it inside the loop...

```
<% @teas.each do |t| %>
  <h2><%= link_to t.flavor, tea_path(t.id) %> - <%= t.brand.name %></h2>
  <% link_to "Write a review", new_tea_review_path %>

  <div>
    <p><%= t.description %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'd also recommed changing your loop variable to `tea` instead of `t`. Its more descriptive and avoids conflicts.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that you will need to pass `tea` to the `new_tea_review_path`